# wsdl2h can't connect to https

Tags: linux, ssl, https, gsoap

I'm trying to use gSoap to connect to a web service secured with https.  However, when I run wsdl2h with an https url, it throws the following error:

```
Cannot connect to https site: no SSL support, please rebuild wsdl2h with SSL or download the files and rerun wsdl2h
```

I'm building on Fedora Core 14.  I have installed openssl-devel and zlib-devel using yum.  What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default wsdl2h is built without support for SSL.  The README.txt file in the wsdl code folder of the gsoap distribution contains the following:

> USING SSL FOR HTTPS TRANSFER OF WSDL FILES
>
> You must build the WSDL parser with 'make secure' to build an
>   SSL-enabled version of wsdl2h that can access HTTPS secure sites.
>
> If you don't have OpenSSL installed, you cannot build an SSL-secure
>   version of wsdl2h. In that case we recommend downloading the WSDL and
>   schema files for processing with the non-SSL-enabled wsdl2h tool.

So you need to either download the .wsdl file manually and run you existing wsdl2h on it or rebuild wsdl2h with **make secure** so that it knows to include the SSL libraries and support for https.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at least with 2.8 "make secure" just does not work.
The trick is to define BOTH CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS to be -DWITH_OPENSSL, and LDFLAGS to be -lssl like:

```
    CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS) -DWITH_OPENSSL' CXXFLAGS='$(CXXFLAGS) -DWITH_OPENSSL' \
    CPPFLAGS='$(CPPFLAGS) -DWITH_OPENSSL' LDFLAGS='$(LDFLAGS) -lssl' ./configure \
            --prefix=/usr \
            --exec-prefix='$${prefix}' \
            --mandir='$${datadir}/man' \
            --infodir='$${datadir}/info' \
            --enable-ipv6 \
            --enable-samples
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by building wsdl2h.exe using Visual Studio 2005 and run the script with the new wsdl2h.exe I compiled.

The project location in gsoap (2.8.17) is "gsoap-2.8.17\gsoap\VisualStudio2005\wsdl2h"

I had to add 'WITH_OPENSSL' in preprocessor of project properties.
Also, I had to add some include and lib directories and some .c files in the project to resolve compile errors.

The point is to build wsdl2h.exe using 'WITH_OPENSSL' option. That will resolve the issue.